'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION' when importing jsx component
I am attempting to import a jsx component into Express.
I am attempting to integrate this component with a library that insists on the use of "import" statements and not the old "require".
When I attempt to import the component I get the error "ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION(ext, filepath)".
Here are a few of the things I've tried:
Based on the advice from this SO post I added:
require("@babel/register")({
  presets: ["preset-react", "preset-env"],
  extensions: [".ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx"],
});

But because I need to use "import" the server crashes. So based on this SO post I added:
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

so that I can use the require hook that Babel provides. I still receive the 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION' error.
Lastly I made a config.js that sat one layer higher than my server.js based on another SO post.
config.js:
require('@babel/register')({
    presets: ["preset-react", "preset-env"],
    extensions: [".ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx"],
})
// Import the rest of our application.
module.exports = require('./server.js')

I still receive the same 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'.
I am unsure of how to proceed, it seems as though others have been able to find a work-around but none of their solutions are working in my case. Any thoughts or tips are greatly appreciated.
For Reference:
server.js
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

require("@babel/register")({
  presets: ["preset-react", "preset-env"],
  extensions: [".ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx"],
});
import { register } from "./babelRegister.js";

import express from "express";
import * as React from "react";
import { renderAsync } from "@react-email/render";
import { Resend } from "resend";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";

import { JobMarkedComplete } from "./emails/Needer/JobMarkedComplete.jsx";

const app = express();



dotenv.config();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  })
);


app.listen(8000);

console.log("here i am");

const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_API_KEY);

app.post("/sendNeederWelcomeEmail", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("nice");
  const { data, error } = await resend.emails.send({
    from: "Acme <onboarding@resend.dev>",
    to: ["delivered@resend.dev"],
    subject: "hello world",
    html: "<p>changed where new resend is instantiated</p>",
  });

  if (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error });
  }

  res.status(200).json({ data });
});


package.json:
{
  "name": "fulfilemailapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "newStart": "babel-node --presets preset-react server.js",
    "dev": "email dev",
    "build": "node --experimental-loader @node-loader/babel ./lib/build.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.24.6",
    "@node-loader/babel": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-email/components": "0.0.19",
    "@react-email/render": "0.0.15",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-email": "2.1.4",
    "resend": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.1"
  }
}


babel.config.js
export default {
    sourceType: "module",
    presets: [
        ["env"],
      [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        {
          runtime: "automatic",
        },
      ],
    ],
  };


As a guess, you shouldn't include the . in the extensions array items.

Hey! Thanks for the suggestion, I tried running that and still no dice.

Oh also you're passing a single string that is comma-separated, but that's an array so it should have multiple strings with commas separating the array items.

I noticed that as well, and tried running it with the only parameter I needed ( extensions: [".jsx"]) and the error persisted. It's a bit of a doosie unfortunately!

That still has the . in the extension name FYI.

FIX Node.js for .jsx files
Hello to you,
Your entire approach is good.
The problem you encounter, namely the ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION error, occurs because Node.js, even with @babel/register, does not natively support the .jsx extension for ES (ECMAScript) modules.
To use JSX in your files, you must use a tool like Babel or Webpack to transpile the JSX into JavaScript before executing it in Node.js.
So you have two solutions:

Either you rename your .jsx to .js, but we can't always do that and I see that this is not what you want from your approach.

Or you want to keep your .jsx and in this case, you have to make some adjustments that you have already started to do from what I see.


To make sure you don't forget anything, I'll give you the different steps:

Install babel and the necessary dependencies:

npm install babel @babel/core @babel/preset-react @babel/register

create a babel.config.json or .babelrc file at the root of your project.

(Make sure it is at the root of your project.)

copy this code into the file you just created.

⚠️ Each extension must be between double quotes ⚠️

{
"presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
"extensions": [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
}

In package.json make sure you have put the right path for your package entries.

main : Main file used when someone imports the package into their project,

module : Specify the file exported as a module. (optional)

exports : Specifies how files are exported when this package is used in other projects (import and required for different modules). (optional)


it should look something like this:

"main": "./src/lib/DIR_NAME/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_PACKAGE.jsx",
"module": "./src/lib/DIR_NAME/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_PACKAGE.jsx",
"exports": {
".": {
  "import": "./src/lib/DIR_NAME/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_PACKAGE.jsx",

  "require": "./src/lib/DIR_NAME/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_PACKAGE.jsx"

}

Once all this is done don't forget to build if necessary and normally it should work as you want.
if you keep getting ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION, you can either:

Either rename the files to .js (but still use JSX syntax)
However, using Babel as shown above should fix the issue without renaming.

Or modify the custom loader.


In this case you need to follow these steps:

Install Babel and Babel-loader.

npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-react @babel/preset-env babel-loader --save-dev

Configure Babel.

Create a .babelrc file in the root of your project with the following configuration to support JSX:

{
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
"extensions": [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
}


Update Webpack configuration.

Edit your webpack.config.js file so that Webpack recognizes .jsx files:

module.exports = {
module: {
rules: [

  {

    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,

    exclude: /node_modules/,

    use: {

      loader: "babel-loader"

    }

  }

]

},
resolve: {
extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]

}
};

This configuration allows Webpack to correctly handle .jsx files with Babel, without the need to rename your files.
